# Try block behavior with cout statements when an exception is thrown

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

If a try block contains cout statements before an exception is thrown in that same block, will those statements be printed to the console, or will it behave as if the try block was never executed?  For example:

```
void foo()
{
  try
  {
    cout << "1" << endl;
    cout << "2" << endl;
    bar();               //exception thrown in this function, but caught below
  }

  catch (exception e)
  {
    cout << e.what();    //assume the message is "error"
  }
}
```

Would the output of this function be

```
1
2
error
```

or

```
error
```

Comment: What output did you get when you tried it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output would be

```
1
2
error
```

The exception does not "undo" the effects of

```
cout << "1" << endl;
cout << "2" << endl;
```